# ThreeJS cannot use on <canvas> tag but only on <div> tag

Tags: three.js

New to WebGL and tried the example code: http://aerotwist.com/static/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/sample.zip

It works on div id="container" tag but when I change it to canvas id="container" it doesn't.

Comment: ummm, why do you want to change the div to a canvas?

Comment: What about the fallback to CanvasRenderer will it work properly on div tag.

Comment: Both the webgl renderer and the canvas renderer render within a canvas dom element.

Answer (score 0):

Both the webgl renderer and the canvas renderer render within a canvas dom element.
You do not change the container div.

to have a fallback to CanvasRenderer you would use code something like this:

```
if (window.WebGLRenderingContext) 
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
else
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```